# Erro - 4058 código em vue js

Tags: vue.js

npm rum serve
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\\\TodoList\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\\\TodoList\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\\\_logs\2024-03-31T02_48_53_797Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Boas-vindas. Para continuarmos dentro da [finalidade do site](/help) é importante você [edit] a pergunta e fornecer o [mcve] do problema, de forma a facilitar a identificação e servir como referência para futuros visitantes. *Agradecemos a compreensão*.

Comment: `npm rum....`não seria `run`?